# I need help figuring out how to find the sum of odd numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to write a program that finds the sum of every odd number in a list of 21. this is what I have so far...

```py
sum = 1
numbers = range(1,21,1)
for number in numbers:
   if number % 2 == 1;
   total += numbers
print(total)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `sum(range(1, 22, 2))`

Comment: The wording is unclear: in a list of 21 random numbers or in the first 21 numbers?

Comment: @Pynchia Interestingly his `range()` gives 20 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either already creating a range of odd numbers simply by asking the range to "jump" by 2, starting from 1: 1,3,5,.. and then summing it all:

```
res = sum(range(1,21,2))
print(res)
>> 100
```

Or, 
create the range, and filter the odd numbers, and then sum it all:

```
r = range(1,21)
filtered = filter(lambda x: x%2, r)
res = sum(filtered)
#or in 1 line: sum(filter(lambda x: x%2, range(1,21)))
print(res)
>> 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You had 3 issues:

1) You called on total but never defined it (total+=numbers) while i think you meant to use sum

2) You wrote Total += numbers instead of +=**number**

3) In this line if number % 2 == 1: you accidentaly used ; instead of :

Here is the fixed code, Enjoy!

EDIT: I want to add that range() is non inclusive, so if you want 21 to be in the list you should use range(1,22,1)

```
sum = 0
numbers = range(1,21,1)
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 1:
        sum += number
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
numbers = range(1,21+1)
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 1:
        sum += number
print(sum)
```

or

```
sum = 0
numbers = range(1,21+1, 2)
for number in numbers:
    sum += number
print(sum)
```

by the way:
`range(start, stop, steps)` doesn't include stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Imported Modules
import time
import decimal


# Functions
def FindOddNums(a, b):
    b = b + 1
    for i in range(a, b):
        # checks if i / 2 is a float and if float cannot be converted into a int if so than execute below code
        if isinstance(i / 2, float) and not float.is_integer(i / 2):
            # Check if b is more than 20 if so then no need to wait 1 sec before printing
            if b > 20:
                print(i)
            elif b < 20:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i)


def AskWhat():
    time.sleep(1)
    num1 = input("What first number do you want to check?: ")
    time.sleep(1)
    num2 = input("What second number do you want to check?: ")
    time.sleep(1)
    # User input is strings so need to be converted to ints
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)
    FindOddNums(num1, num2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AskWhat()
```

Is this what you're looking for?

This actually calculates the thing but using steps is also a good way to go. But this is another way